# Conditionally change resource name Activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'd like to conditionally change the label of a resource in ActiveAdmin based on the user role. I'd like to keep the default pluralization of the name for admins, but for regular users, I need to change the name.

I.e. I have a resource `Users`, which I would like to change to `My Account` for the regular user (since they won't see #index).

I'm trying something like

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  menu :if => proc {if !current_user.admin? 
    menu :label => "My Account"
  else
    menu :label => "I hate Users"
  end}
```

Anyone know how to conditionally name the resource?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
menu :label => proc { true ? "I Hate Users" : "My Account" }
```

But then to access the

```
    current_admin_user
```

or the

```
current_user
```

object from within the *proc* won't work. I haven't found a way to get the logged in user object from within the ActiveAdmin::MenuBuilder scope. There are suggestions, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2513456/790737 where you set a variable in

```
Thread.current
```

after succesfull login. I guess you will have to hook in to the post-authentication work of devise. Good luck.