# Rails/devise current_user accessed in model but it's nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model, devise, controller

I needed to access the **current_user** in my another model. I googled and found a few solutions and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2513456/1552570).

But just one difference: I didn't set the **User.current_user** in the controller. **WHY?**

Like in the answer I followed **I'm not adding data to my second model from views but by rendering data via a url (with open-uri, it's csv data I'm fetching).**
So in my second model I do:

```
Person.create(username: User.current_user.username)
```

It gives:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

which isn't working (which is obvious I guess). In console when I do User.current_user it shows:

> 1.9.3p448 :002 > User.current_user
>   => nil

I think why it isn't working is because I'm accessing the **User.current_user** directly from model and model cannot get the current_user unless it is given that. (right?)

But this would definitely work if I access it via a login page and set the User.current_user in the controller.

But as **I'm directly fetching the data from url**, **I'm directly making new entries for my Person model in model itself.**

So how do I set the User.current_user?

Is there any workaround for this? Edit's for the question's title are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_user` is available by default as a helper method within Devise. From [the documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise):

```
# For the current signed-in user, this helper is available:
current_user
```

The `current_user` isn't accessed directly via the model, per se, but rather, though the Devise module, which looks up the `User` object that is logged into the current session, and then returns to `current_user`.

Thus, the current user isn't accessed via `User.current_user` (there is no `current_user` method on `User`, as the error message is saying). You access it purely by invoking the `current_user` helper method within a controller or view.

**UPDATE**:

You're well advised to keep your controller and model layers separate. One way of doing what you've proposed is to create a class function on the `Person` model wherein you explicitly pass the `username` of your `User` object from within your controller:

```
# in your controller
Person.create_with_username(:username => current_user.username)

# app/models/person.rb
def self.create_with_username(username)
    self.create(username)
end
```

Comment: I know that current_user is not a method which can be called on User class.But if you see the link I followed it assings the `current_user` to `User.current_user`. Also I want to access this current_user in my model.

Comment: Did you read all the comments indicating that the cited solution __is not thread safe__? You understand that this invariable __will__ cause you problems, correct? The model should be stateless and agnostic to your application state, so the following solution is a far better avenue, IMO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12713768/1086529

Comment: Have you had any luck with the update to my question? Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: May I recommend that you do try it and report back with you findings. If it doesn't work, we can move on to finding another solution.

Comment: okay but will that `create_with_username` method be called automatically within the model every time I make a new **Person?**

Comment: If you invoke `Person.create_with_username(:username => current_user.username)`, then yes, it will.

Comment: Nope. That's not working. May be I'm wrong but I don't think that's gonna work (or the only answer to this question is 'NO' ) because `current_user` is stored in the sesssion I guess. So only when a user is logged in via a browser of so then only we have a value in `current_user`.Only working on model level and invoking a controller action is not possible.

Comment: I've tested this and it _does_ work. What is not working about it?

Comment: @zeanstoi the `current_user.username` value is `nil`. How will it work? From where will you invoke the `Person.create_with_username(:username => current_user.username)`?

Comment: Do you mean to suggest that you need to access `current_user` without being logged in? You do understand that that is __not__ how Devise works, correct? It's not even how the answer you've linked to works. Who is the `current_user` if not the ___current user___, after all?

Comment: @zeanstoi Yeah. The CSV I'm fetching,have data of many **Persons** which belongs to a **Company**. here the company is the `current_user`. So in my model I fetch the csv and make `persons`. But as I have a `has_many` association from company to person I want to assign the company's username to each person of that company.So obiviously when I'm creating `persons`(indirectly via open-uri/csv) the company isn't logged in. That's why I asked for a workaround for this issue.