# Devise current_user helper method only works in users_controller.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

As the title suggests, the devise helper methods are only working in users_controller.rb. If I try to access it in any other controller (even applications_controller.rb) after sign-in, im getting this error.

```
Routing Error
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for ApplicationController:Class
```

Im just adding `puts current_user` in applications_controller.rb.

This is my `routes.rb`

```
 devise_for :users
 resources :users
```

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails/devise current\_user accessed in model but it's nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562143/rails-devise-current-user-accessed-in-model-but-its-nil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current_user is not a class method so it won't be available directly in ApplicationController

it would be available in all the `action` and `before_action`

Use the below logic to check the value of the `current_user` in you Application Controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action do
    puts current_user
  end
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Please let me know if you still face any issues

Comment: Its showing up. I was getting the error cause the "puts current_user" was not inside a method/function.

Comment: Glad to help you