# Fetching a sum for the current_user, accessible through a js.erb partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model Expense.rb, in which a user has many. New expenses can be added through an ajax form and thus I have the appropriate files setup (create.js.erb, destroy.js.erb.. etc)

Currently when a new expense is submitted via the remote form, an amount sum is also updated in the create.js.erb, which in my Expense model looks like this:

```
def total_value
    Expense.sum(:amount)
end
```

create.js.erb:

`$('#total').html('$<%= number_with_delimiter(@expense.total_value) %>');`

The problem is this sums all expenses from the database whereas I need to just find for the current_user (which I know is not accessible from the model).

Inside my controller, on the index action I'm doing it like so:

```
@expenses = current_user.expenses
    @total_value = @expenses.sum(:amount)
```

which means I can fetch it for the current_user in my index view by just doing:
`<%= number_with_delimiter(@total_value) %>`

but as for the create action:

```
def create
    @expense = Expense.new(secure_params)
    @expense.user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @expense.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to index_expense_path }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

I'm not sure how to go about passing the current_user to total_value in the model in order to sum just for the current_user id in total_value which is used in the create js.erb.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513383/access-current-user-in-model

Comment: @RajeshCO I'm trying to identify the correct MVC way to do this, I saw that link before, not sure if any of the answers inside are the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expense.sum(:amount) takes all the expense records out.

Changing

```
def total_value
    Expense.sum(:amount)
end
```

to:

```
def self.total_value
    sum(:amount)
end
```

would call self, so doing

```
current_user.expenses.total_value
```

should work, and if you do `Expense.total_value` will still keep working.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is this sums all expenses from the database whereas I need
>   to just find for the current_user (which I know is not accessible from
>   the model).

Perhaps you could use a `scope` & pass the `user id` to it:

```
#app/controllers/expenses_controller.rb
def total_votes
   Expense.user(current_user).sum(:amount)
end

#app/models/expense.rb
Class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :user, ->(user) { where(user_id: user.id) }
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ended up not needing to use scope.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need a total_expenses method in your User model:

```
Class User

  has_many :expenses

  def total_expenses
    expenses.sum(:amount)
  end
end
```

Then you can just call

```
current_user.total_expenses
```