# Rails ActiveRecord validates deep relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

There can be many `Organisations`

A `User` belongs to an `Organisation`

An `App` belongs to an `Organisation`

An `Env` belongs to an `App`

When creating an `Env` an `App` is chosen

What kind of `validates` can I write to check that the `App` belongs to the same `Organisation` as the `current_user` does?

Comment: Maybe it should be something in the controller, since it seems quite hard to get the current user inside the model

Answer (score 0):

`User.current` is a pattern described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513383/access-current-user-in-model/2513456#2513456)

```
validate :app_must_belong_to_the_same_organisation_as_user

def app_must_belong_to_the_same_organisation_as_user
  unless User.current.organisation == app.organisation
    errors.add(:base, "User's and app's organisations mismatch!")
  end
end
```

Comment: I updated my answer. How you want to access your current_user is up to you. You could as well pass the current_user to the `App` object from controller if you do not want to use `User.current`

Answer (score 0):

```
#app/models/app.rb
Class App < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :organisation

    validates :app_user_organisation?

    private

    def app_user_organisation?
        organization == [[current_user]] #-> still working out current user
    end
end
```