# active model serializer with parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, active-model-serializers

I'm using Active Model Serializer and I need to include a parameter that is within the scope of the controller. For example, I'm serializing over posts, but there is a condition between the current_user (variable in PostController) and posts in the Serializer.

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
attributes :id, :active, :favorite

def favorite
  if current_user.favorites.find(object.id) != nil
    return true
  end
end
```

however, the current_user is undefined. Is there anyway I can send the current_user as a parameter into the Serializer?

thanks a ton!

Comment: Which version are you using? At least in 0.10 the `current_user` will be defined on the serializer. I believe in previous versions it was accessible through the `scope` method.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Active Model Serializers are you using?  I'm using 0.8.3 anyway it has an options param so you could call the serializer like

```
PostSerializer.new(post, :current_user => current_user)
```

and access the current_user option like

```
def favorite
  if options[:current_user].favorites.find(object.id) != nil
    return true
  end
end
```

However I suspect it would be cleaner to actually serialize a user which happens to have a relationship to favourite posts

Comment: This works! I have been searching for hours!! In my app, I put this in my controller   render json: @posts, :user => User.find(params[:user_id])

Comment: For others using newer versions of AMS (version 0.10.5 in my case) --  `options` is now `instance_options`.

So instead of `options[:my_var]` you would use: `instance_options[:my_var]`

Answer (score 0):

i think that this will be the best:

```
def favorite(user)
  if user.favorites.find(object.id) != nil
    return true
  end
end
```

just pass the user into the method, because devise `current_user` use session which not readable straight forward from your model.

other option is read this post:

[Access current_user in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513383/access-current-user-in-model)