# How do i specify conditions in my "includes" clause of my Rails query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, include, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I have this model

```
class MyObjectTime < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
  has_many :user_my_object_time_matches
```

and then in my controller I have this for querying some of that model

```
  @results = MyObjectTime.joins(:race,
                            "LEFT JOIN user_my_object_time_matches on my_object_times.id = user_my_object_time_matches.my_object_time_id #{additional_left_join_clause}")
                     .where( search_criteria.join(' and '), *search_values )
                     .limit(1000) 
                     .order("my_objects.day DESC, my_objects.name")
                     .paginate(:page => params[:page])
                     .includes(:user_my_object_time_matches)
```

My question is, although I want all the MyObjectTime objects returned, subject to certain criteria, I don't want all of the "user_my_object_time_objects" attached to each model, only ones satisfying certain criteria (e.g. those whose user_my_object_time_match.user_id field is null or equal to "30").  How do I specify criteria to force only certain user_my_object_time_matches included for each of my MyObjectTime models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**includes** is used for eager loading, so I assume you want load `MyObjectTime` records along with `user_my_object_time_matches` associations, so you don't have to query the database anymore.

The way that **includes** work is this:

```
MyObjectTime.where(search_criteria.join(' and '))includes(:user_my_object_time_matches)
```

That would query the database twice:

- load all MyObjectTime records, subject to the search_criteria

  ```
  SELECT * FROM my_object_times WHERE (....)
  ```
- load all associated `UserMyObjectTimeMachine` records

  ```
  SELECT * FROM user_my_object_time_machines WHERE my_object_time_id IN ( [ids returned by the previous query ])
  ```

So if you want to add additional filtering on the second query, then in the model `MyObjectTime` you can add another association:

```
class MyObjectTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :user_my_object_time_matches
  has_many :user_my_object_time_matches_with_null_user, -> { where("user_id IS NULL or user_id = 30") }, class_name: "UserMyObjectMatch"
```

and then when you call

```
MyObjectTime.where(search_criteria.join(' and ')).includes(:user_my_object_time_matches_with_null_user)
```

the second query will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_my_object_time_machines WHERE (user_id IS NULL OR user_id = 30) AND my_object_time_id IN ( [ids returned by the previous query ])
```

With that your example would look like this:

```
@results = MyObjectTime.joins(:race)
                       .where( search_criteria.join(' and '), *search_values )
                       .limit(1000) 
                       .order("my_objects.day DESC, my_objects.name")
                       .paginate(:page => params[:page])
                       .includes(:user_my_object_time_matches_with_null_user)
```

**With no eager loading**

If the condition is not the same everytime (user_id IS NULL OR user_id = 30), then I don't know a good way to eager load everything. So you can just use normal left join, but then query would be performed when you try to get the association records:

```
 @results = MyObjectTime.joins(:race,
                            "LEFT JOIN user_my_object_time_matches on my_object_times.id = user_my_object_time_matches.my_object_time_id AND (user_my_object_time_matches.user_id IS NULL or user_my_object_time_matches.user_id = 30)")
                     .where( search_criteria.join(' and '), *search_values )
                     .limit(1000) 
                     .order("my_objects.day DESC, my_objects.name")
                     .paginate(:page => params[:page])
                     .includes(:user_my_object_time_matches)
```

You can find good chunk of documentation in the **Eager Loading of associations** here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: This fundamentally changes the results that are being returned, right?  that's not what I want.  In your query, I will only get results in which "MyObjectTime" is linked to a record taht has "user_my_object_time_matches.user_id IS NULL OR user_my_object_time_matches.user_id = 30" but I only wish to remove those results from the objects taht are returned, not block the parent object from being returned  altogether.

Comment: Yes, you are right - it will change the result. Let me edit the answer

Comment: Awesome, so this definitely gets me closer.  The last thing is in your answer you have hard-coded "30" due to what I listed in my example.  In real life, the value I want to screen by will be the id of the user in my session, e.g. "current_user.id".  Is there a way to pass a parameter to the "user_my_object_time_matches_with_null_user" you have in the MyObjectTime model?

Comment: I see. I don't know of a way to pass a parameter (current_user in your case) to the has_many scope through **includes** method, but as an option I see you making the current_user accessible in the model. You use Rails 5, so check this answer for how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513383/access-current-user-in-model#2513456 and then you would be able to change the scope to: 

`has_many :user_my_object_time_matches_with_null_user, -> { where("user_id IS NULL or user_id = ?", Current.user.id) }`

Comment: Great link.  I believe I have followed everything from your example, but I'm noticing taht when I try and access that field, 'puts "first: #{@results[0].user_my_object_time_matches_with_null_user}"', I get teh error, "uninitialized constant MyObjectTime::UserMyObjectTimeMatchesWithNullUser".

Comment: Sorry, I missed very important detail in my answer - there should class_name attribute in the has_many relationship: `has_many :user_my_object_time_matches_with_null_user, -> { where("user_id IS NULL or user_id = 30") }, class_name: "UserMyObjectTimeMatch"`. The reason behind it is to show Rails which class to use. Will edit the answer too.