# Child not being created from Parent model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a checkbox that if checked allows my child resource called Engineer to be created. I'm trying to create it through my model since that's where I can call the `after_save` method.

Here is my code:

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :armies
  has_many :engineers  
end
```

**models/army.rb**

```
class Army < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :engineers
 attr_reader :siege
 after_save :if_siege
 private

 def if_siege
   if self.siege
    Engineer.create!( :user_id => current_user.id, :army_id => self.id )
   end
 end
end
```

**models/engineer.rb**

```
class Engineer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :army
end
```

**controllers/armies_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @army = Army.new
end

def create
  @army = current_user.armies.build(params[:army])
    if @army.save
      redirect_to new_army_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

This gives me an error though for my `if_siege` method:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user'
```

How can I fix this or is there another way to do this? Not sure if this should go in the controller or model but I only can wrap my head around putting this in the model.

Thanks.

Comment: @jordanpg its a Devise method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `belongs_to :user` to the `Army` model

In `Army#if_siege`, update `Engineer.create!` as follows

```
Engineer.create!( :user_id => self.user.id, :army_id => self.id )
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the current_user object won't exist within the context of the Model layer unless your authentication is doing something to make it available. This is usually a non Threadsafe approach though. Maybe for you this isn't the issue.

[Current User Instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568218/access-to-current-user-from-within-a-model-in-ruby-on-rails)

Having said that, one way (perhaps not the ideal way) to address this is by creating an attr_accessor in the model on the object called Army. Then set the current_user to this in the Army *new* action in the controller where the current_user instance is available.

```
# in the Army model
attr_accessor :the_user

# in the Army Controller
@army = Army.new(:the_user => current_user.id)
```

You will also have to add a hidden field to store this value in your view to carry this through to the create action.

Just an observation, but I'm fairly sure in the "if_seige" method the *self* calls are redundant. *self* should already be scoped to the Army object in that method.