# Where to put a method to be commonly used in model, controller and view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have a method to be accessible in Model, Controller as well View . But it will not be a model specific function i.e. not to be executed over model object.

Where should I declare such a function moreover I do not want to use view_context or such thing

Comment: What is the method and what does it do?

Comment: it returns the current user

Comment: This is a bad idea because it can lead to really poor code design and is hard to maintain. I would suggest rethinking what you're trying to do and see if there's a better way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access to current\_user from within a model in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568218/access-to-current-user-from-within-a-model-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

You can define a static method in `config/environment.rb`

```
def self.my_global_method
 "Hello!!"
end
```

And you can call it from anywhere

```
my_global_method # => "Hello!!"
```

Make sure you define the method before `YourApp::Application.initialize!`

Comment: Thanks Shiva, yes we may but i feels that it will not be the best method coz its not model related function

Comment: @Akshat Hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Find one way:- To define method in initializers.Can anyone have another answer to this