# how access to helper "current_user" in model rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, controller, helper

I need to call current_user (define in ApplicationControler like an helper), in my `User` model.

I test ApplicationController.helpers.curret_user but not works:

```
irb(main):217:0> ApplicationController.helpers.current_user
NoMethodError: undefined method `current_user' for nil:NilClass
```

but this method works fine in controllers and views...

So how can I get my current user in model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't (or, at the very least, you really really *shouldn't*).

Your models have no access at all to your currently instantiated controller. Your models are supposed to be designed in such a way that there might not even *be* a request or a user actually interacting interactively with the system (think [ActiveJob](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html)).

You need to pass `current_user` *into* your model layer.

---

Your specific problem is that you've invented something called `helpers`. That isn't a thing, it's `nil`, so you get your `NoMethodError` on `nil:nilClass` error. `current_user` is an *instance* method, so you would need to invoke it directly on an *instance* of your controller, not on the class itself.

Comment: ok, lot of things are forbidden, it's difficult to me. I'm accustomed to be free in choice AND rigorous in code...

Comment: @Matrix You should give up on free choice. There are very strongly defined conventions in Rails, and you should follow them, especially at the beginning when you don't know enough to pick and choose which conventions can safely be disregarded. Rails as a whole is very powerful, but it does a *lot* for you, but only if you actually use it correctly.

Comment: I agree you should follow the rails convention.  You can see a sample of how I would recommend using it on a github project I have.  https://github.com/camdixon/nku-rails/blob/master/app/controllers/application_controller.rb   and then use it like this current_user     and you can call attributes on it like current_user.id in views if needed.  It's not a symbol so no need to use a colon in front or after it if you use it like I did in the github link.

Comment: @camdixon Actually I wouldn't advise he use that controller as a basis. Your before filters aren't idiomatic by a stretch. Don't `return true`, that doesn't *do* anything. Either render/redirect, or do nothing. http://pastebin.com/3VRDm8im

Comment: Ok, my bad for referencing it.  Should I delete previous comment?  Would you recommend using the current_user helper in that way?

Answer (score 8):

if you in your ApplicationController call helper_method :current_user

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user])
  end
end
```

Than you can call it in your helpers

[more docs on](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods:helper_method)

Answer (score 7):

I just answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568469/2449774

Copied for convenience:

I'm always amazed at "just don't do that" responses by people who know nothing of the questioner's underlying business need.  Yes, generally this should be avoided.  But there are circumstances where it's both appropriate and highly useful.  I just had one myself.

Here was my solution:

```
def find_current_user
  (1..Kernel.caller.length).each do |n|
    RubyVM::DebugInspector.open do |i|
      current_user = eval "current_user rescue nil", i.frame_binding(n)
      return current_user unless current_user.nil?
    end
  end
  return nil
end
```

This walks the stack backwards looking for a frame that responds to `current_user`.  If none is found it returns nil.  It could be made more robust by confirming the expected return type, and possibly by confirming owner of the frame is a type of controller, but generally works just dandy.

Comment: Works perfectly inside `ApplicationHelper`, thank you.