# How to access current_user object in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to write a method in my "team" model but current_user is showing this error

undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #

```
def set_default_url
  if current_user.id == self.user_id
    "/assets/default_black_:style_logo.jpg"
  else
    "/assets/default_:style_logo.jpg"
  end
end
```

The method current_user is working fine for other models and controllers . I am calling this method like this .

```
has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { 
  :medium => "200x200#", 
  :thumb => "100x100#", 
  :small => "50x50#" 
}, 
:default_url => :set_default_url
```

I am using rails 3.2 , ruby 1.9.3 and devise 3.1 . It seems to be simple task but I don't understand where the fault lies . I will be really thankful if someone helps me out here .

Comment: You might want to have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568218/access-to-current-user-from-within-a-model-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Have you set any association of `User` model with `Team` model?

Comment: @GaganGami Yes! of course

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`current_user` is not available in any model, to access `current_user` in model do this

In your application controller

```
before_filter :set_current_user

def set_current_user
  Team.current_user = current_user
end
```

in your `Team` model add this line

```
cattr_accessor :current_user
```

Congrats, now `current_user` is available in every model, to get the current user just use the following line everywhere

```
Team.current_user
```

NOTE: Restart the server after adding the lines mentioned above!

Now in your question you can use it like

```
def set_default_url
  if Team.current_user.id == self.user_id
    "/assets/default_black_:style_logo.jpg"
  else
    "/assets/default_:style_logo.jpg"
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Team.current_user is returning nil even if I am logged in

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry, I missed a line, in application controller add this line `before_filter :set_current_user`, I have edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it only once than while calling this method pass current_user as argument like

```
has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { 
  :medium => "200x200#", 
  :thumb => "100x100#", 
  :small => "50x50#" 
}, 
:default_url => :set_default_url(current_user)
```

and in model

```
def set_default_url(current_user)
  if current_user.id == self.user_id
    "/assets/default_black_:style_logo.jpg"
  else
    "/assets/default_:style_logo.jpg"
  end
end
```

If you dont want above step then follow these

Go to User Model

```
def self.current_user
  Thread.current[:user]
end

def self.current_user=(user)
  Thread.current[:user] = user
end
```

Then go to application controller

```
before_filter :set_current_user

def set_current_user
  User.current_user = current_user
end
```

Now we can easily fetch current_user in any model not only in Team

just give as User.current_user so in your code

```
def set_default_url
  if User.current_user.id == self.user_id
    "/assets/default_black_:style_logo.jpg"
  else
    "/assets/default_:style_logo.jpg"
  end
end
```

So make use of it.

Hope it solves your issue in a good way. Free to use in any model

User.current_user           to fetch the current user 
User.current_user=          to assign the current user.

Thanks