# Accessing current_user devise method from rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using devise in a rails app I'm building. I'd like to get the ID of the user that is currently signed in, with current_user.id, in my controller, without passing it as a parameter from my view. Is there any way I can do this? Thanks

Comment: I must ask it, have you tried using `current_user.id`?

Comment: @Sebastián Palma yes I tried it and got tihs error: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed Devise properly and have not broken something by overriding the Devise controllers, you should be able to access `current_user.id` from the controller.  This method will only work if a user is signed in which you can test with the `user_signed_in?` method.  Finally, this assumes that the resource name Devise is using is indeed `user`.  That is the default, but it is possible to configure Devise to work with different resource names.

Comment: @RT5754: The `current_user` method should be available in all controllers in the starter app you linked.

Comment: and if I created new controllers do I have to include devise or something in them to access tehese methods?

Comment: If you follow the instructions in the Devise documentation, you should not have to do anything to make `current_user` available.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The answer on this post worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804532/undefined-local-variable-or-method-current-user-using-devise-rails-3-2

Comment: That makes sense. Your question indicated that you wanted to access `current_user` in your controller, not in your model.  I am not sure what your particular use case is, but I would generally recommend against trying to access `current_user` in your model.  It is usually better to keep that logic in a controller or in a helper.   Regarding the SO questions linked above, I would have put that logic in a helper.

Comment: I do want to use it in my controller. This solution works for accessing it there