# Rails: Hide "Edit" and "Destroy" unless logged in as Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, pundit, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm brand new to rails, and am creating a simple glossary app using Rails 5 with gems Devise and Pundit. I generated an Admin model with Devise; that's the only role that needs to be logged in. I installed Pundit to create policies that would allow me to hide the "Edit," "Destroy," and "New" buttons unless logged in as admin.
[Glossary App Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOQKi.jpg)

After adding the below policy code to my index.html.erb file to hide the 'Edit' and 'Destroy' buttons, I'm getting an "Undefined method 'current_user'" error.

```
<tbody>
      <% @terms.each do |term| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= term.name %></td>
          <td><%= term.category %></td>
          <td><%= term.definition %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', term, class: 'btn btn-mini' %></td>
          <td>
            <% if policy(@term).edit? %>
              <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_term_path(term), class: 'btn btn-mini' %>
            <% end %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <% if policy(@term).destroy? %>
              <%= link_to 'Destroy', term, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-mini', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
            <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

Since I didn't generate a "User" model with Devise, but generated an "Admin" model instead, it seemed logical that the error was referring to the word "user" in my new policies. So I replaced "user" with "admin" in my application_policy.rb and terms_policy.rb. Clearly I don't understand what "user" means in this error, as I'm still getting it.

I don't know what exactly you need to see, so here are my models, controllers, and policies:

**application_record.rb**

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

**admin.rb**

```
class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :terms
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :trackable, :timeoutable, :lockable
end
```

**term.rb**

```
class Term < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :admin

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where(["name LIKE ?","%#{search}%"])
    else
      all
    end
  end

end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_current_user

  def set_current_user
    Term.current_user = current_user
  end
end
```

**terms_controller.rb**

```
class TermsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_term, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, :only => [:new, :edit, :create, :destroy]

  # GET /terms
  # GET /terms.json
  def index
    @terms = Term.search(params[:search])
  end

  # GET /terms/1
  # GET /terms/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /terms/new
  def new
    @term = Term.new
  end

  # GET /terms/1/edit
  def edit
    @hide_edit_button = true
  end

  # POST /terms
  # POST /terms.json
  def create
    @term = Term.new(term_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @term.save
        format.html { redirect_to @term, notice: 'Term was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @term }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @term.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /terms/1
  # PATCH/PUT /terms/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @term.update(term_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @term, notice: 'Term was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @term }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @term.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /terms/1
  # DELETE /terms/1.json
  def destroy
    @term.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to terms_url, notice: 'Term was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_term
      @term = Term.find(params[:id])
    end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def term_params
  params.require(:term).permit(:name, :category, :definition)
end

def verify_is_admin
      (current_admin.nil?) ? redirect_to(root_path) : 
(redirect_to(root_path) unless current_admin.admin?)
    end
end
```

**application_policy.rb**

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :admin, :record

  def initialize(admin, record)
    @admin = admin
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    false
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    false
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    false
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(admin, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :admin, :scope

    def initialize(admin, scope)
      @admin = admin
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

**terms_policy.rb**

```
class TermPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def index?
    true
  end

  def create?
    user.present?
  end

  def update?
    return true if user.present?
  end

  def edit?
    user.admin?
  end

  def destroy?
    user.admin?
  end 
end
```

I've tried implementing suggestions from [Access to current_user from within a model in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568218/access-to-current-user-from-within-a-model-in-ruby-on-rails), [undefined local variable or method `current_user' using devise & rails 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804532/undefined-local-variable-or-method-current-user-using-devise-rails-3-2), https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authorization-with-pundit--cms-28202, and a smattering of other sources. I'm sure these are all great resources, but at this stage I need something a little more targeted to my project and level of familiarity with Rails.

Let me know what else I can provide. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you have to use `current_admin` acording to the [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) _If your devise model is something other than User, replace "_user" with "_yourmodel"_

Comment: Thanks inye. I'm guessing you're referring to the application_controller.rb, so I've replaced "_user" with "_admin". The error that I'm getting now is, "undefined method `set_current_admin' for #<TermsController:0x97d2d28> Did you mean? set_current_user"

I'm not sure how to define this method in my terms_controller. If I were to guess, that would be a private method:
    def set_current_admin
    end

Comment: you define the `set_current_user` in the `aplication_controller.rb` I think you have to change the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pundit looks to `current_user` in your controller to get the user record. You can [configure](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#customize-pundit-user) this with the `pundit_user` method. Override it in  `application_controller.rb` to return your Admin record.

```
def pundit_user
  Admin.find_however_you're_doing_that
end
```

For what it's worth, you're likely going about this a painful way if you intend to add additional roles (non-admin users). You likely want a single Devise model with roles defined as an attribute.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That makes sense, and I've edited the `application_controller.rb` as you've suggested. I'm still getting the same error. Apparently I've really gone off the rails *cough* here, so I'm seeing if creating a new app with this info you guys have provided will be cleaner and easier to troubleshoot. Regarding user roles, that's a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try to add some

```
  before_action :ensure_admin, except: [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_action :ensure_admin_or_user, only: [:edit, :update, :account]
```

in your controller

with method =>

```
  def ensure_admin
    if current_user.nil? || current_user.is_at_least?(:manager) == false
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t('must_be_admin')
      redirect_to root_path
      return true
    end
    false
  end
```

Hopes its helps you !

Comment: Thank you Jordan. I've added the before_actions and defined the ensure_admin method the way you've suggested, and it came back with an error that 'current_admin' is undefined. So I pulled my _empty_ 'set_current_admin' method from the application_controller over to the terms_controller.rb, and it seems to have had no effect.