# Using devise within the models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Is there a way to use devise functions within a model? Let's say, a scope?

For reference, this is what I was thinking of:

```
scope :available, -> {
    if user_signed_in?
        requestable
    else
        requestable.where.not(books: {owner_id: current_user.id})
    end
}
```

I would need to use `user_signed_in?` and `current_user` in this scope. But I can't. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Why can't you use them? Both of those methods are available in other models, for example a `User` model would require devise, as that is the purpose of the gem.

Comment: Ohh duh. They are set up to be used within controllers not models. I was being forgetful sorry!

Comment: So the answer would be a straight 'No'? That would be ok (just disappointing) :(

Comment: It is highly discouraged.... I'll write up a quick answer but I'm not sure how much help I can be.

Comment: Seems like I was beat to it! After looking at axel's answer, I'd actually mark this as a duplicate of the question he linked (even though it is not strictly devise, it is essentially the same problem/solution) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568218/access-to-current-user-from-within-a-model-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate, but fairly similar. I guess the answer is `It can#t be done, and it shouldn't`. I will be accepting his, since it adds quite some reasoning to it. thanks to everyone who contributed.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a very helpful answer, but is the only one I know of. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods like these are not meant to be used in models. Models are supposed to work outside the controller as well (i.e. directly from the Rails console).

For a more detailed reasoning see:

[Access to current_user from within a model in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568218/access-to-current-user-from-within-a-model-in-ruby-on-rails)

Further there is no global 'store' knowing which users are currently signed in - this is determined within a request, by veryfying the user sends valid session information with his request.

Answer (score 2):

`current_user` (and same goes for devise helpers such as `user_signed_in?`) is only available in your controllers. I've been around that question and ended up by passing `current_user` to my scopes and model's methods.

In the model:

```
scope :available, -> (current_user, signed_in) {
    if signed_in
        requestable
    else
        requestable.where.not(books: {owner_id: current_user.id})
    end
}
```

In the controller:

```
MyModel.available(current_user, user_signed_in?)
```

---

An alternative would be to use [request_store](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store)  (rack based global data storage) to store the `current_user` of the current request

Comment: I guess I am better off doing the logic about the user in the controller, and adapt my scopes around it. Passing in them as parameters feel clunky. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Good thought. Though I feel that's perhaps where MVC reach its limits, cause it seems right to me to have data such as `current_user` to be globally accessible