# ruby on rails - current_user on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I need to call `current_user` on a model (I have installed `devise`).
I use this method but it doesn't work:

```
class Todo
  def category_name
    category.try(:name)
  end

  def category_name=(name)
    self.category = Category.find_or_create_by(name: name, user_id: current_user)
  end

end
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: how you try to invoke this methods?

Comment: Anywhere. What result you expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to current\_user from within a model in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568218/access-to-current-user-from-within-a-model-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: From the console, I get an error because there is no variable current_user

Comment: If you try to explain what you're exactly trying to do here, then perhaps we can help. Having `current_user` in model is not really a good idea.

Comment: from todo form I want to assign a category to the new todo (and create it if necessary) with the name and associate it (category) with the logged user

Comment: Have you tried accessing it through self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current_user` is a devise helper to be used on Views and Controllers. If you have an instance method that needs the `current_user` you should probably move it's logic to a Controller.

It's better explained here: [Access to current_user from within a model in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568218/access-to-current-user-from-within-a-model-in-ruby-on-rails?lq=1)